# <html> vertical centers page content and creates padding or margins

Tags: html, css

*this is how my page looks:*

[image]

## How do i get rid of the red/html/body & centering?

**Note**

- *wanted outcome*: Everything to fill page without any red visible
- the same happens when the content-wrapper expands beyond 100vh

**darkred** is *html* 
**lightgray** is *header* 
**gray** is *main* 
**blue** is *content wrpper* 
**gold** is *footer*

```css
:root {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: var(--header-height);
  margin-bottom: var(--footer-height);

  --header-height: 10vh;
  --footer-height: 3vh;
  --footer-padding: 2vh;

  --color-first: #42b797;
  --color-text: #328b73;
  --font-header: "Nunito", sans-serif;
  --font-lobster: "Lobster", cursive;
  --font-roboto: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  /*
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  
  */
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*Header*/

header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  height: 10vh;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #666;
}

.header-active {
  color: var(--color-first);
}

.header-logo,
.header-list,
.header-authenticate {
  padding: 1vh;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  font-family: var(--font-header);
  font-weight: 600;
}

header h1 {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  color: var(--color-first);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-logo {
}

.header-list {
  display: flex;
  flex: 2;
}

.header-authenticate {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

/*END Header*/
/**/

.content-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  min-height: 50vh;
}

main {
  /* margin-top: var(--header-height); */
  /* padding-bottom: calc(var(--footer-height) + var(--footer-padding) / 2); */
  background-color: #333;
  min-height: 10vh;
  /* min-height: calc(200vh - (var(--header-height) + var(--footer-size))); */
  position: relative;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  font-size: 0.5rem;

  background-color: darkgoldenrod;
  padding: var(--footer-padding) 0;
  height: var(--footer-height);
  width: 100%;

  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

html {
  background-color: darkred;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!---->
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://certificate.wiki" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/global.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/index.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/master.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/mobile.css" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <!---->
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Upload you certificates from udemy, linkedin or school and show them of to your employer, friends and family"
    />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!---->
    <title>Certificate</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1><a href="" class="header-logo">Stianlife.com</a></h1>

      <ul class="header-list">
        <li>
          <a href="" class="header-item header-home header-active">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="" class="header-item header-certificate">Certificate</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="" class="header-item header-about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="" class="header-item header-profile">Manage Profile</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="header-authenticate">
        <li>
          <a href="">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="">Sign up</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </header>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <main>
        <div class="background"></div>
      </main>
      <footer>
        <p>© 2020 - Stian Håve - About</p>
        <p>
          this work is licenced under Creative Commons Attributions 4.0
          International license
        </p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your adding padding to --root thereby pushing your body away from the top and bottom

Remove this from the --root styles

```
margin-top: var(--header-height);
margin-bottom: var(--footer-height);
```

Also `position:absolute` is relative to the closest `position:relative` parent so your applying `bottom:0` to your footer is positioning it to the bottom of the content-wrapper, you probably want to remove `position:relative` from content-wrapper and then `bottom:0` will work the way you expect it.

Check out Positioning contexts [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning)

Comment: Well that's embarassing, forgot i added those there... welp, only took me 4 hours of staring at the screen to realize that i added padding to to the root...

Comment: Anyhow, thank you very much! i spent waay to long looking at this. I appreaciate your help!

Comment: Sure happens to the best of us. Happy to help